# Reverse Python Bytecode

Tags: python

I try reverse python bytecode (Content in a .pyc file). I do not want to decompile the code, just understand the Python bytecode :)

The LOAD_NAME statement, pushes the value associated with co_names (tuple of names of local variables...) [namei] onto the stack. (How can I check these values contained in co_names?)

[image: n]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`marshal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html) module to load the code object.

Now, suppose you want to find out what does `LOAD_NAME 1` loads on the evaluation stack.

```
import marshal

co = marshal.load(...)
print co.co_names[1]

# Or if you want to print the entire co_names
print co.co_names
```

Refer to the [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html?highlight=co_names) module for further reference.